# Darboux integrable implying continuous integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If $f$ is Darboux Integrable on $\mathbb{R}$, is $g(x) = \int\limits_{0}^{x}f$ continuous? I haven't been able to find anything on this, so if this is a duplicate, please let me know. I would appreciate seeing a hint to the proof of this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is yes but the title is misleading because $g'(x)$ need not equal $f(x)$ generally.  E.g., this won't happen where $f$ has a jump discontinuity.

Comment: How should I word the title?

Comment: I guess I would use the word "integral" instead of "antiderivative".

Comment: Thank you! If you could give me a hint on the proof, I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof of the statement that I figured out for myself.

Let $[a,b] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary interval such that $[0,x] \subseteq [a,b]$. If $c \in [a,b]$, then note that 
$|g(x) - g(c)| = \left|\int\limits_{0}^{x}f - \int\limits_{0}^{c}f\right| = \left|\int\limits_{c}^{x}f\right|$.

Since $f$ is integrable, $f$ is bounded. So $\exists M \geq 0$ such that $|f| \leq M$. Then since $|f(y)| \leq M$ $\forall y \in [a,b]$, it follows that $-M \leq f(y) \leq M$, or \begin{equation}-M(x-c) \leq \int\limits_{x}^{c}f \leq M(x-c) \implies \left|\int\limits_{x}^{c}f\right|\leq |M(x-c)| = M|x-c|\text{.}\end{equation}

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Choose $\delta := \dfrac{\epsilon}{M}$ such that $|x - c| < \delta$. Then

\begin{equation}
|g(x) - g(c)| = \left|\int\limits_{c}^{x}f\right| \leq M|x-c| < M\delta = \epsilon\text{.} \end{equation}

Hence $g$ is continuous. $\square$

Comment: +1: You've answered your own question correctly.  Note that you've shown rather more than just that $F$ is continuous: it is, in fact, a Lipschitz function: i.e., there is a constant $C$ such that $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)| \leq C|x_1-x_2|$, namely $C = M$, a bound for $|f|$.  Lipschitz functions are uniformly continuous with $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{C}$ (as you've shown) and have many other nice properties.

Comment: By the way, most undergraduate level analysis texts include a proof of this statement early on in their discussion of the Riemann/Darboux integral.  See e.g. Theorem 8.1 (literally the first theorem in the chapter on integration) of http://math.uga.edu/~pete/2400full.pdf.